# Командная оболочка Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Не очень понял что такое командная оболочка и что такое дочерняя командная оболочка. Как я сейчас понимаю:

Терминал - это есть командная оболочка, которая работает на языке Bash (может быть другой). При написании мною в терминале команд, он их считывает, интерпретирует и выполняет. Выполнение команд происходит на дочерней командной оболочке (которая графически не видна).
Тобишь:

Я пишу в терминале вызов скрипта. Он считывает что я ввел и начинает выполнять скрипт. Само выполнение происходит на дочерней оболочке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда скрипт выполнится, то результат передастся в основную командную оболочку, где скрипт был вызван, и отобразится. (в A )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это так, то:

1)Сколько может быть дочерних оболочек?

2)Если скрипт имеет промежуточные выводы, то они будут отображены в A или в дочерней оболочке?

3) Если я открыл несколько терминалов, то у каждого будет своя оболочка?

4) Можно ли как то отобразить дочернюю оболочку?

5) Как в сущности представлять оболочки?

(Например: массив я могу представить как область в памяти)

Исходя из этого примера:

```
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ var3=три
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ var4=четыре
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ export var4
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ echo $var3 $var4
три четыре
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ bash
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ echo $var3 $var4
четыре

[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ export var5=пять
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ echo $var3 $var4 $var5
четыре пять
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ exit
exit
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ echo $var3 $var4 $var5
три четыре
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$
```

Что то очень похожее на наследование из ООП. А представляется как 2 уровня (1 видимый,а 2 нет) в которых 2 наследуется от 1 и как-то между собой взаимодействуют.

P.S Если дочерних оболочек может быть несколько, то var4 (из примера) будет в каждой?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89274/discussion-on-question-by-qada---linux).

Answer (score 2):

> Терминал - это есть командная оболочка

Терминал - это **железяка**. В Linux - устройство, зарегистрированное в системе под именем вроде */dev/tty00* и так далее.

> что такое командная оболочка

Это **программа**, которая считывает команды пользователя с клавиатуры терминала и выполняет эти команды. В Linux существует много много разных командных оболочек. В частности:

- sh
- bash
- zsh
- ...

Все эти программы обобщённо называются "оболочка" - shell. Они достаточно сильно различаются, но идеология у них одна - ввести и обработать команду пользователя. Что такое "команда" я тут не буду объяснять, но скажу лишь, что большая часть команд - это команды запуска других программ.

Этой **другой** программой может быть и программа командной оболочки. Т.е. из одного shell мы можем запустить другой shell - дочерний.

Причём дочерний shell вовсе не обязан быть того же типа, что и родительский. Количество дочерних оболочек ограничивается только допустимым количеством процессов в системе.

В момент загрузки ОС ядро просматривает свой список **устройств** терминалов и на каждый запускает программу логина. После того, как вы ввели свой логин и пароль, система смотрит файл /etc/passwd и достаёт оттуда имя шелла, которым пользуетесь именно вы.

ОС запускает именно эту **программу** командной оболочки и передаёт ей имя **устройства** терминала, на котором выполнен логин.

Эта программа считывает ваши команды и исполняет их.

Если вы запустили дочерний шелл, то он получит то же самое устройство. При этом он будет получать ваш ввод (родитель его не получит) а выводить они оба будут в окно одного **устройства** терминала.

Есть тонкости, но я о них говорить здесь не буду.